# linux command to remove leading whitespace

Tags: linux, text-processing

I just wanted to extract VmRSS value, but the print should not show leading whitespace

```
renv@svr-ubt20-004:~$ cat /proc/607440/status | grep VmRSS
VmRSS:     20452 kB
```

Tried `tr` and `cut` commands and got below results.

```
renv@svr-ubt20-004:~$ cat /proc/607440/status | grep VmRSS | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr -s " "
         20452 kB
```

**Expectation:**
20452 KB

Needed help to achieve this.

Comment: The character between : and number in that 'file' is **tab not space**. Even if you 'squeeze' it, one tab still displays as 8 spaces (on common terminal emulations). You need to delete it, which `tr -d` could do, but (like awk) sed can do the whole job at once: `sed -n 's/VmRSS:\t//p' /proc/N/status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK can take care of all this:

```
awk '/VmRSS/ { print $2" "$3 }' /proc/607440/status
```

Answer (score 2):

Try either of these:

```
sed -n 's/^VmRSS:\t//p' /proc/607440/status

awk 'sub(/^VmRSS:\t/,"")' /proc/607440/status

awk -F':\t' '$1=="VmRSS"{print $2}' /proc/607440/status
```

I'm assuming above that that's a tab after the `:` in your sample input since your `tr -s " "` didn't compress it. If that assumption is wrong then using POSIX tools:

```
sed -n 's/^VmRSS:[[:space:]]*//p' /proc/607440/status

awk 'sub(/^VmRSS:[[:space:]]*/,"")' /proc/607440/status

awk -F':[[:space:]]+' '$1=="VmRSS"{print $2}' /proc/607440/status
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl:**

```perl
~$ zsh
~% printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | perl -lpe 's/^VmRSS\:\t//;'
20452 kB

~% bash
~$ printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | perl -lpe 's/^VmRSS\:\t//;'
20452 kB
```

---

**Raku:**

```perl
~$ zsh
~% printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | raku -pe 's/^VmRSS\:\t//;'
20452 kB

~% bash
~$ printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | raku -pe 's/^VmRSS\:\t//;'
20452 kB
```

Also for Raku, you have various `trim`, `trim-leading`, and/or `trim-trailing` functions built-in. For those times when you just need to get rid of whitespace and don't care if it's spaces or tabs, etc.:

```perl
~$ zsh
~% printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | raku -pe 's/^VmRSS\://;' | raku -ne '.trim-leading.put;'
20452 kB

~% bash
~$ printf 'VmRSS:\t20452 kB' | raku -pe 's/^VmRSS\://;' | raku -ne '.trim-leading.put;'
20452 kB
```

---

MacOS Ventura 13.4

zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)

GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)