# Remove exact line from file if present, leave the rest of lines; error-handling - how to go about it

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, posix, error-handling

I am not exactly sure how text processing should be done in a good way, so let me ask.

I have this file: `~/.config/mpv/input.conf` containing possibly other options as well as `v disable`.

If I want to remove that line from the file, I suppose I could do:

```sh
grep -v -q -F 'v disable' input.conf; echo $?
1
```

Where - if the file contains nothing else like now, it would return 1 ([man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html) says `1` - "No lines were selected."), which troubles me as I cannot run a simple `if-statement`.

So I would have to store `$?` after the command and then check if it is greater than 1 for error.

Also, it is unclear to me, if replacing the file in-place is a good idea:

```sh
grep ... input.conf > input.conf
```

---

If there is some other way, let me know. Also if portions of my suggestions are correct, please let me know.

Thanks, and cheers.

---

EDIT1:

Desired behavior is to toggle between the state where there is this line (done with simple `>>` addition after a check if it is there, and is not (remove it, thus this question).

EDIT2:

The accepted solution must be POSIX-compliant. No *bashisms* or non-POSIX tools. You can, however, include non-POSIX solutions which might be useful for other people. In any case, thanks.

Comment: You can run an if on a command for example `if grep -q 'v disable' input.conf; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"`.  Is that what you mean?  Also a more sane way is to create a temp file then move the temp to the original file. So no `input.conf > input.conf`, rather `input.conf > tmp.conf && mv -v tmp.conf input.conf`

Comment: You could also use `sed -i 's/^v disable$//g' input.conf` to modify the file in-place.

Comment: @Panki Wow, that easy... Thank you, post an answer, I'll read it test it and accept it.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Aha, so it could cause problem modifying it the way I described. Thank you!

Comment: @VlastimilBurián yes. you are welcome. Also if you will be using sed then `sed -i.bak '/^v disable$/d'` might be what you want. Or for properly editing files you can use `printf '%s\n' '/^v disable/d' 'wq' | ed -s input.conf`

Comment: Actually, the command by @Panki doesn't remove the line, but replaces it by an empty line. Valentin's command is correct plus it keeps a backup in case of unintended changes.

Comment: What is your desired outcome when a one-line file matches? Do you want the file emptied of all content? Or deleted?

Comment: @jubilatious1 See Edit1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `grep` will return 0 (true) iff one or more lines matches the RE you provide. The `-v` flag inverts this, so `grep` will consider all lines that do not match the RE as successful. In this instance the only time you'll get a failure on a `v`-match is when there is exactly one line in the source and that it exactly corresponds to your RE.

Therefore, removing a matching line and also returning an indication that the change was applied is a little more complicated:

```
remove='v disable'
if grep -qxF "$remove" input.conf
then
    # Apply the removal, saving a backup
    cp -fp input.conf input.conf.bak &&
        grep -vxF "$remove" input.conf.bak >input.conf

    # Do other things that are relevant if the line was removed
else
    # Do things that are relevant if the line was not present
    :
fi
```

An alternative suggestion from [Valentin Bajrami](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43380/valentin-bajrami) was made [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749558/remove-exact-line-from-file-if-present-leave-the-rest-of-lines-error-handling/749566?noredirect=1#comment1425902_749558) to use [`ed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) to modify the file directly in place:

```
if printf '%s\n' '/^v disable/d' wq | ed -s input.conf >/dev/null
then
    # Do other things that are relevant if the line was removed
    :
else
    # Do things that are relevant if the line was not present
    :
fi
```

Note that in this instance the matching string is treated as an RE rather than a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Note, this answer has been updated in response to an excellent comment from @roaima.*

The Raku code below tells you how many linewise matches to a Regex are found in a file. The `given`/`when` pattern is basically Raku's "switch" (or "case") statement. Once a match is found it is stored in the `$/` (or `$<>`) variable:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my regex RE { ^^ v \s disable $$ };
            given "/path/to/original.txt".IO.lines() {
                when $_.elems  > 0 and none / <RE> / { say "no match"; };
                when $_.elems == 1 and      / <RE> / { say "one line file, with match"; };
                when $_.elems  > 1 and      / <RE> / { say "multi-line file, with match"; };
                default {say  "error"; }
            };'
```

Thus (for example), in the third `when` statement above (*"multi-line file, with match"*), the following code can be appended to the end of that `when` block:

```
#`(  
     spurt("/path/to/original_bak.txt", $_.subst(:global, "$/ "), createonly => True);
     unlink("/path/to/original.txt".IO) if "/path/to/original_bak.txt".IO  ~~ :e & :f;;
     copy("/path/to/original_bak.txt", "/path/to/original.txt", createonly => True)
  )
```

Error handling is built-in for the three file-operations above: see [spurt](https://docs.raku.org/routine/spurt), [class X::IO::Unlink](https://docs.raku.org/type/X/IO/Unlink), and [class X::IO::Copy](https://docs.raku.org/type/X/IO/Copy). You can add [File Test Operator](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path#File_test_operators) statements to test even more aspects.

The `spurt` statement writes to a new `_bak` file, `unlink` unlinks the original, and `copy` copies the `_bak` backup file to the original name, leaving two files. Remove the multi-line comment designators (first and last lines), and change both instances of `createonly` to `False` once you're satisfied the code is working correctly (as judged by text return values).

You can do similar for *"one line file, with match"* case, or just change the conditional to combine two `when` statements into one. If you don't like the one-liner format you can save as a script, make executable, run as a cron job, etc.

---

Below are previous answers (both Raku and Perl) which don't do error handling:

**Raku:** `~$ raku -ne '.put  unless /^v\sdisable$/;' input.conf > tmp_input.conf`

**Perl:**  `~$ perl -ne 'print unless /^v disable$/;'  input.conf > tmp_input.conf`

These answers are pretty close to the `sed` answer posted by @Panki, the advantage being here Perl/Raku will remove the blank line created. See the second link below for an explanation of Perl/Raku differences.

Perl can do `-i` "in-place" replacement; Raku cannot. But you can adapt the third link below to use shell redirection to circumvent the Raku limitation (make backups first, in any case!).

---

*NOTE: Raku isn't POSIX-compliant as the OP requests in an edit. I'm leaving this answer up for anyone seeking a non-POSIX approach.*

https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#given-when
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749407/227738
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204378/227738
https://raku.org